Just Soli and Human Rights
Jus Soli grants citizenship for being born in a country.  If the parents are foreigners the baby will probably have dual citizenships.
Citizenship comes with privileges and obligations.  Morally speaking, does it make sense to bind a person to its citizenship obligations if he lived in that country for just a few days as a baby?  Theoritically as an adult he could be later forced to military service, paying income tax and other without using any of the citizenship privileges, not even living/visiting there or owning a passport for that country! 
Universal Declaration of Human Rights says :

Article 15

Everyone has the right to a nationality.

No one shall be arbitrarily deprived of his nationality nor denied the right to change his nationality.



This seems to suggest that anyone should be able to renounce to a citizenship without any consequences.
Question is how easy this should be to respect the essence of Article 15?
In the US, for instance, it costs 2350$ to renounce citizenship, the process is fairly complex and the person may have to pay tax for the last 5 years.

@MichaelHall Agreed!  I edited the question.

without any consequences. - what are you basing this part on?

Neither "Morally speaking, does it make sense" nor "how easy this should be to respect the essence" are good legal questions.  If you have a question about the law please clarify, otherwise what you are asking is subjective and opinion based.

Acquiring a new citizenship is usually a years-long process involving significant processing fees, comparable to the fees for the renunciation of US citizenship you cite (note that they seem to be reducing the fees again). That is not usually viewed as a violation of the UDHR. So I see no problem if the release from citizenship requires some paperwork as well.
The US has come under some criticism for the payments they demand (compare this BBC article). Other countries demand that citizens do military service first, or refuse the release entirely.
In summary, it is generally understood that changing a citizenship does come with significant consequences and administrative hurdles, and Article 15 was not meant to make the switch available at the drop of a hat.

That seems legally fair for an adult adopting a new citizenship.  The question is more  about accidental citizenship and opting out of this unwanted citizenhip without hurdles.

@user56898, the UDHR makes no exceptions for children in this regard. So while there is a problem, it is minor.
